# Reset Snow Leopard user accounts/preference

Tags: snow-leopard, user-account

My kids completely changed everything in their user account, what is the easiest way to reset everything to default (without reinstalling everything) including:

- Name of hard drive
- Menu items in Finder
- Dock size and items
- Size/appearance of things
- Even some applications have been moved from their original location

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Name of hard drive
  Click enter, rename it
- Menu items in Finder
  What do you mean by that?
- Dock size and items
  Trashing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` will do the trick
- Size/appearance of things
  Trashing the `.plist` file under `~/Library/Preferences`
- Even some applications have been moved from their original location
  You'll have to move them back to `/Applications` manually.

In order for that not to be reproduced, you could try `Parental Controls` under `System Preferences` > `Account` and limit what they can do on their account.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Loïc’s excellent answer

> **Menu items in Finder**
>
> What do you mean by that?

I believe he means the Finder’s Sidebar and such. In order to reset those, thrash the following file and logoff (or restart):

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist
```

> **Even some applications have been moved from their original location**
>
> You'll have to move them back to
> /Applications manually.

Yes, unless he has a Time Machine backup… which I believe he doesn’t. :)

Comment: Yep, you were right I meant the Finder's Sidebar. I do have a Time Machine + Time Capsule for the kid's iMac but I thought it may be easier just to reset things than dig through backups.

Comment: @Abdullah for the Apps it might be easier to restore them with TimeMachine, just go to Time Machine while in the /Applications folder and scroll back “in time” -> restore, overwrite, keep old :) Some app might need an update but at least you’ll have them back.